# CSS button position

Tags: html, css, button

I have code below for a contact form I have created. When you click preview, a second page view comes up. Is it possible to get the "Submit" button in the same position as the "Preview" button? Anything helps, cheers.

```js
function openNav() {
    var input = document.getElementById("txtDetail");
    var value = input.value;
    var label = document.getElementById("labelDetail");
    label.innerHTML = value;
  
    var input = document.getElementById("txtName");
    var value = input.value;
    var label = document.getElementById("labelName");
    label.innerHTML = value;
  
    var input = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
    var value = input.value;
    var label = document.getElementById("labelNumber");
    label.innerHTML = value;
    
    var input = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
    var value = input.value;
    var label = document.getElementById("labelEmail");
    label.innerHTML = value;
  
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Verdana", Verdana;
}

#contact {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  height:477px;
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#contact h5 {
  text-decoration:underline;
  display: block;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contact h6 {
  text-decoration:underline;
  display: block;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left:25px;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#button{
  float:right;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 13px 32px;
  width:125px;
  height:45px;
  border: none;
  font-family:Verdana;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#button:hover{
  background: #43A047;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:125px;
    height:45px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
input[type="file"]{
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  width:125px;
  height:45px;
  border: none;
  font-family:Verdana;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
.custom-file-upload:hover{
    background: #43A047;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.custom-file-upload:active{
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}



.overlay {
    height: 477px;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 5px;
  margin-top:-15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
#contact-submit{
  float:right;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 13px 32px;
  width:125px;
  height:45px;
  border: none;
  font-family:Verdana;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact-submit:hover{
  background: #43A047;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact-submit:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#label{
  padding-left:25px;
  float:left;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:13px;
}
#labelDetail{
  padding-left:25px;
  float:left;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:13px;
}
#labelName{
  padding-left:25px;
  float:left;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:13px;
}
#labelNumber{
  padding-left:25px;
  float:left;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:13px;
}
#labelEmail{
  padding-left:25px;
  float:left;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact">
    <h3>Connect With HR</h3>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Location</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Category</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <textarea id="txtDetail" placeholder="Detail...." tabindex="2"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
      <h4>Contact Information</h4>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <input id="txtName" placeholder="Name" type="text" tabindex="4" >
        <input id="txtNumber" placeholder="Preferred Contact Number" type="tel" tabindex="5">
        <input id="txtEmail" placeholder="Preferred Email" type="email" tabindex="6">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Attachment
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
      <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    
    
    
    
    <div class="container">
        <h5>Summary</h5>
          <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <label id="label">Location:</label>
      </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <label id="label">Category:</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <label id="label">Detail:</label>
        <label id="labelDetail"></label>
      </fieldset>
            <h6>Contact Information</h6>
          <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <label id="label">Name:</label>
            <label id="labelName"></label>
            </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <label id="label">Preferred Contact Number:</label>
            <label id="labelNumber"></label>
            </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <label id="label">Preferred Email:</label>
            <label id="labelEmail"></label>
            </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>  
<span id="button" onclick="openNav()">Preview</span>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
So here's the full code - 
add "collapsed" class to the html div id=myNav
toggle this class on the 2 clickHandlers (openNav and closeNav)
give the anchor tag X close a z-index: 100;
give the "collapsed" class the relevant css.    


<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font-smoothing: antialiased;
      text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    }

    .container {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
    }

    #contact input[type="text"],
    #contact input[type="email"],
    #contact input[type="tel"],
    #contact textarea,
    #contact button[type="submit"] {
      font: 400 12px/16px "Verdana", Verdana;
    }

    #contact {
      background: #F9F9F9;
      padding: 25px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
      height:477px;
    }

    #contact h3 {
      display: block;
      font-family:Verdana;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #contact h4 {
      margin: 5px 0 15px;
      display: block;
      font-family:Verdana;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    #contact h5 {
      text-decoration:underline;
      display: block;
      font-family:Verdana;
      font-size: 23px;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #contact h6 {
      text-decoration:underline;
      display: block;
      text-align:left;
      padding-left:25px;
      font-family:Verdana;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .fieldset {
      border: medium none !important;
      margin: 0 0 10px;
      min-width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #contact input[type="text"],
    #contact input[type="email"],
    #contact input[type="tel"],
    #contact textarea {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background: #FFF;
      margin: 0 0 5px;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    #contact input[type="text"]:hover,
    #contact input[type="email"]:hover,
    #contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
    #contact textarea:hover {
      -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
    }

    #contact textarea {
      height: 100px;
      max-width: 100%;
      resize: none;
    }

    #button{
      float:right;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 13px 32px;
      width:125px;
      height:45px;
      border: none;
      font-family:Verdana;
      background: #4CAF50;
      color: #FFF;
      margin: 0 0 5px;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    #button:hover{
      background: #43A047;
      -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    #button:active {
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    #contact input:focus,
    #contact textarea:focus {
      outline: 0;
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
    }

    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #888;
    }

    :-moz-placeholder {
      color: #888;
    }

    ::-moz-placeholder {
      color: #888;
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: #888;
    }

    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 13px;
        font-size: 16px;
        width:125px;
        height:45px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    input[type="file"]{
        display: none;
    }
    .custom-file-upload {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 13px 16px;
      width:125px;
      height:45px;
      border: none;
      font-family:Verdana;
      background: #4CAF50;
      color: #FFF;
      margin: 0 0 5px;
      font-size: 15px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .custom-file-upload:hover{
        background: #43A047;
      -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .custom-file-upload:active{
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }



    .overlay {
        height: 477px;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
    }

    .overlay.collapsed {
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    .overlay-content {
        position: relative;
        /*top: 5%;*/
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        /*margin-top: 25px;*/
    }

    .overlay-content .container {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .overlay-content fieldset:last-child {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .overlay a {
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top:-15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 36px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .overlay .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
      .overlay .closebtn {
        font-size: 40px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
      }
    }
    #contact-submit{
      float:right;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 13px 32px;
      width:125px;
      height:45px;
      border: none;
      font-family:Verdana;
      background: #4CAF50;
      color: #FFF;
      margin: 0 0 5px;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    #contact-submit:hover{
      background: #43A047;
      -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    #contact-submit:active {
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    #label{
      padding-left:25px;
      float:left;
      font-family:Verdana;
      font-size:13px;
    }
    #labelDetail{
      padding-left:25px;
      float:left;
      font-family:Verdana;
      font-size:13px;
    }
    #labelName{
      padding-left:25px;
      float:left;
      font-family:Verdana;
      font-size:13px;
    }
    #labelNumber{
      padding-left:25px;
      float:left;
      font-family:Verdana;
      font-size:13px;
    }
    #labelEmail{
      padding-left:25px;
      float:left;
      font-family:Verdana;
      font-size:13px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">  
      <form id="contact">
        <h3>Connect With HR</h3>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
          <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Location</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Category</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
          <textarea id="txtDetail" placeholder="Detail...." tabindex="2"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
          <h4>Contact Information</h4>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <input id="txtName" placeholder="Name" type="text" tabindex="4" >
            <input id="txtNumber" placeholder="Preferred Contact Number" type="tel" tabindex="5">
            <input id="txtEmail" placeholder="Preferred Email" type="email" tabindex="6">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
          <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Attachment
    </label>
    <input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
          <div id="myNav" class="overlay collapsed">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <div class="overlay-content">




        <div class="container">
            <h5>Summary</h5>
              <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <label id="label">Location:</label>
          </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <label id="label">Category:</label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <label id="label">Detail:</label>
            <label id="labelDetail"></label>
          </fieldset>
                <h6>Contact Information</h6>
              <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <label id="label">Name:</label>
                <label id="labelName"></label>
                </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <label id="label">Preferred Contact Number:</label>
                <label id="labelNumber"></label>
                </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <label id="label">Preferred Email:</label>
                <label id="labelEmail"></label>
                </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="fieldset">
          <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>  
    <span id="button" onclick="openNav()">Preview</span>
          </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").classList.remove("collapsed");
        var input = document.getElementById("txtDetail");
        var value = input.value;
        var label = document.getElementById("labelDetail");
        label.innerHTML = value;

        var input = document.getElementById("txtName");
        var value = input.value;
        var label = document.getElementById("labelName");
        label.innerHTML = value;

        var input = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
        var value = input.value;
        var label = document.getElementById("labelNumber");
        label.innerHTML = value;

        var input = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
        var value = input.value;
        var label = document.getElementById("labelEmail");
        label.innerHTML = value;

        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
        document.getElementById("myNav").classList.add("collapsed");
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Above is the full code - changes are just; Add "collapsed" class to the html div id=myNav; toggle this class on and off in the javascript in functions "openNav" and "closeNav"; give the anchor tag X a z-index: 100; apply the relevant css to the "collapsed" class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Messing around quickly here;

Take percentage margins off .overlay-content and add padding to .overlay in the same manner as the previous screen (25px). Commented out previous code

.overlay {
    height: 477px;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding: 25px;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    /*top: 5%;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /*margin-top: 25px;*/
}

Then fill .container to 100% height and push the last fieldset down;

.overlay-content .container {
    height: 100%;
}

.overlay-content fieldset:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

Though be careful as a general rule using absolute positioning.
```

Comment: If I do this, when you close the preview screen part of it stays open because of the padding:25px;

Comment: Add a class to the collapsed overlay and remove the padding.